# Simulate select with element-ui and vue-test-utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, element-ui

I'm doing unit tests with Jest and Element-ui in Vue on a component which contains a select with 2 options. I am selecting an option from a dropdown and then checking that an action has been called.

**1)** With normal `select` and `option` HTML tags this works perfectly.

*// Fruit.vue*

```
<template lang="pug">
  select(
    v-model="fruit"
  )
    option(
      v-for="item in fruits"
      :label="item.label"
      :value="item.value"
    )
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      fruits: [
        {
          label: 'Banana',
          value: false
        },
        {
          label: 'Apple',
          value: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fruit: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.fruit
      },
      set (fruit) {
        this.$store.dispatch('setSelectedFruit', { fruit })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

*// DOM*

```
<select>
  <option label="Banana" value="false"></option>
  <option label="Apple" value="false"></option>
</select>
```

*// Fruit.spec.js*

```
it('calls the "setSelectedFruit" action when a value is selected', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Fruit, { store, localVue })
  const options = wrapper.find('select').findAll('option')


  options.at(1).setSelected()
  expect(actions.setSelectedFruit).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

However I use element-ui's `el-select` and `el-option`, which have their own interaction with the DOM.

**2)** With `el-select` and `el-option`

*// Fruit.vue*

Stays the same, except that `select` is replaced by `el-select` and `option` by `el-option`.

*// DOM*

```
<div class="el-select-dropdown">
  <div class="el-select-dropdown__wrap">
    <ul class="el-select-dropdown__list">
      <li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
        <span>Banana</span>
      </li>
      <li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
        <span>Apple</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

*// Fruit.spec.js*

**a)**

```
it('calls the "setSelectedFruit" action', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Fruit, { store, localVue })
  const options = wrapper.find('.el-select-dropdown__list').findAll('el-select-dropdown__items')

  options.at(1).setSelected()
  expect(actions.setSelectedFruit).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

**b)** Given that `setSelected` is actually an alias according to the [vue-test-utils documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setselected), I tried it this way:

```
it('calls the "setSelectedFruit" action', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Fruit, { store, localVue })
  const options = wrapper.findAll('.el-select-dropdown__item')
  const select = wrapper.find('.el-select-dropdown__list')

  options.at(1).element.selected = false
  select.trigger('change')
  expect(actions.setSelectedFruit).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

With the second method, the chosen `option` is set as `selected`, but the trigger on the `select` doesn't work and so the `v-model` isn't updated.

So I'd like to know if someone has a solution for this, or if there is another library (other than vue-test-utils) **with which element-ui's `el-select` can be simulated**.

Comment: have you tried using `select.vm.$emit('change', 1)` instead of `trigger` ? (the 1 being the value of the selected element) or `$emit('input', 1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by triggering a click on the drop down item that you would like to simulate:

```
wrapper.findAll('.el-select-dropdown__item').at(1).trigger('click');
await Vue.nextTick();
expect(YourExpectStatement);
```

The Vue.nextTick() was needed for me, as it allows the DOM to update it's cycle, more [info here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick). Also note you'll need to make your test function async, like:

```
it('Async test name', async () => {
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult to trigger click in `<el-dropdown>` or `<el-select>` and make the dropdown item come out .
And then I try to mock all this element. It works fine for me.

/mock/div.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
    <slot name="dropdown"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({   
  inheritAttrs: true
})
</script>
```

jest.setup.js

```
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Div from './mock/div.vue'
config.global.components = {  
   ElDropdown: Div,
   ElDropdownItem: Div,
   ElDropdownMenu: Div
}
```

Comment: Trying this solution, but i get "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'components')" ... What am i doing wrong ?